# reverse cat files order

Tags: shell, wildcards, cat

I need to do log analysis and I am facing problem that `cat access.log*` display latest log file first.

I tried to sort logs which takes a lot of time because I have logs from couple of years back. And they are already sorted and just displayed in different order than I need it to.

So I need to display files contents in folowing order:

```
access.log.4
access.log.3
....
access.log
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I can't believe that turnkey, unexplained and simple answers to almost non problem generate that many upvotes... No surprise that bash stuff are really trendy today. It's just really a shame that as a consequence, the quality and usefulness of the site as a whole plunges toward zero...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -rt access.log* | xargs cat
```

First list the files from oldest to newest and then `cat` each one of them.

Comment: Great answer, solved my problem. I should learn to use xargs :)

Answer (score 6):

In `zsh` you can reverse the globbing order:

```
cat access.log.*(On)
```

```
~/test % ls
1  2  3
~/test % cat 1
1
~/test % cat 2
2
~/test % cat 3
3
~/test % cat *
1
2
3
~/test % cat *(On)
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat $( ls | tac )
```

or simply

```
cat $( ls -r )
```

Comment: `ls -r` does a reverse order by *file name* but it fails ordering numbers on names so it puts first `access.log.9` than `access.log.32`

Comment: If the number of digits is manageable, you could just do: `cat $( ls -r access.log.?? ) $( ls -r access.log.? )` - but since it's logfiles `ls -rt` as @jcbermu used is applicable.